# Autofill to named range in vba

Tags: excel, vba, range, autofill

I'm trying to write a macro to autofill a range dynamically as you can see in the photo :

[image]

I've tried this code and it return an error :

```
Sub Auto()

Dim selection1 As Range
Dim selection2 As Range
h = 1
g = 1
```

This two loops I used to detect the the first empty cell in column AZ to refer to its range later

```
Do Until Cells(h + 1, 52).Value = ""
h = h + 1

Loop
Do Until Cells(g + 1, 1).Value = ""
g = g + 1

Loop


Set selection1 = Range("AZ" & h & ":" & "BD" & h)



Set selection2 = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ" & g & ":" & "BD" & g)
```

This where I tested the above idea and it worked fine and the range selected as it should as shown in the photo

```
Range("AZ" & h & ":" & "BD" & h).Select


'Autofill
```

This where I got the error:

```
'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AZ" & g & ":" & "BD" & g), Type:=xlFillDefault







End Sub
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: The destination has to include the source.

Answer (score 0):

This will autofill the data down.
The method for finding the last row is the same as going to the last row and pressing *Ctrl+Up*.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AY").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in column AY.
        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in column AZ.

        .Range(.Cells(LastRow2, "AZ"), .Cells(LastRow2, "BD")).AutoFill _
            Destination:=.Range(.Cells(LastRow2, "AZ"), .Cells(LastRow1, "BD"))
    End With

End Sub
```